# How to Change the position of breadcrumbs in list page?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, breadcrumbs, list.phtml, category-listing

I want to display the `breadcrumbs` in list page alone to display inside the grid exactly just above the toolbar.

So I entered this line of code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
```

just above the line :

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

in `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/catalog/list.phtml`.

But nothing is getting displayed.

**I want to change the position of breadcrumbs only in list page.
Why the above procedure not working. Is there anything wrong to use `getChildHtml()` to call block like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getChildHtml()` method only works if there's a corresponding child in the current block.

However, natively Magento breadcrumbs is not a child of the product list, that's why your code is not working.

To do so, you will have to edit/create `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml` with the following code:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <action block="root" method="unsetChild"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
    <action block="product_list" method="insert"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <action block="root" method="unsetChild"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
    <action block="product_list" method="insert"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: Thank you @Raphael at Digital. I have another doubt. I will just post as another question. Guide me in that too please.