# Move breadcrumb position without local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I want to change position of the breadcrumbs without making changes in **local.xml**.

I want the breadcrumbs after the category image, on the list page. How can I do this?

Comment: provide full detail where you want to chnage the position and where you want to put

Comment: Why don't you want to changes the local.xml? You can move it around in the page template itself as it's defined there, but then you won't be able to call it anywhere else. Your other solution would be jQuery but that's client side only

Comment: any specific reason for not want to change in local.xml ?

Comment: if you want to change local.xml then check : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123314/how-to-change-the-position-of-breadcrumbs-in-list-page

Comment: @NikunjVadariya I want to change it at local template,layout level. I know we can use local.xml. But trying to get it done by another way.

Answer (score 0):

To move breadcrumb position, insert the below-mentioned php code just after the category image block code in theme folder app/design/frontend///template/catalog/list.phtml.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
```

Above method steps only work if there's a corresponding child in the current block.

However, natively Magento breadcrumbs are not the child of the product list, that's why above code will not work alone. 
To do so, you will have to edit app/design/frontend///layout/catalog.xml with the following code:

```
<action block="root" method="unsetChild"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
<action block="product_list" method="insert"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
```

Insert afore-mentioned code just above "". You need to insert it for default() and layered()